# Eclipse Run History

Tags: eclipse, configuration, runtime

Does eclipse remember when a program was executed last time? I know there is run configurations, but that doesn't keep track of past executions and their order of execution.

When a program is executed at the shell, then shell keeps tracks of the order of their executions? I want similar utility in eclipse along with the time of execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the debug view or in the console view (click the arrow near screen icon) the program that have run and the start time.
 
Edit : In Preferences/(Run/Debug)/Launching uncheck the "Remove termined launches when a new launch is created".

This list is reset if you clear hit or if you close Eclipse.

If you want a more permanent information, I think your programs should log that info in files.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute your previous most recent program with ctrl+f11. For detail you can go to run->run history.

Comment: That is fine but i want to know what date and time, the given program was executed

Comment: you can compare files only with the local history but not the program execution history(Not very much sure).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the time when your program was executed, make your program output the time by itself. There is nothing in Eclipse that can do exactly what you need.